# Downgrade Azure SQL Database from P15 (2TB) to P4 (500GB)

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

As per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-resource-limits):

> If the maximum size of a database is set to greater than 1 TB, then it cannot be changed to 1 TB even if the actual storage used is below 1 TB. Thus, you cannot downgrade a P11 or P15 with a maximum size larger than 1 TB to a 1 TB P11 or 1 TB P15 or lower performance tier, such as P1-P6).

I wonder why this limitation apply? What are the workarounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I solved the problem using the Export-Import approach. I first exported existing database to the blob and then imported produced bacpac file to the new database. Steps below:

1. Export database `Db` (P15, 2TB)
2. Import bacpac to `Db-New` (P15, 500GB to speed up the process)
3. `ALTER DATABASE [Db] MODIFY NAME = [Db-Old]`
4. `ALTER DATABASE [Db-New] MODIFY NAME = [Db]`
5. Drop `Db-Old`
6. Downgrade `Db` plan to P4

Comment: Glad you were able to get this working.  FYI - I think you can check your own answer as "Accepted" so that the question will appear solved.

Comment: I am also glad to know you were able to export/import your database. Sorry for my delay to provide you a solution/workaround and for explaining too late the reasons behind the limitations.

Answer (score 2):

The answer provide by SQL Azure team is that the downgrade is not possible because there are multiple files on a 4 TB database and the only way to downgrade is exporting the data though something like bcp,

Adding another reason is that those premium tiers of 4 TB reside on a special hardware.

EDIT: Answer updated with information provide by Microsoft.

Comment: Per the documentation linked above, I don't think a simply copy operation will fulfill the objectives `If the maximum size of a database is set to greater than 1 TB, then it cannot be changed to 1 TB even if the actual storage used is below 1 TB..<snip>...This restriction also applies to the **restore and copy scenarios including point-in-time, geo-restore, long-term-backup-retention, and database copy**. Once a database is configured with a maximum size greater than 1 TB, all restore operations of this database must be run into a P11/P15 with a maximum size greater than 1 TB.`

Comment: Let me share this with SQL Azure team and try to find a possible workaround. Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score -3):

**Note:** Once a database is configured with a maximum size greater than 1 TB, all restore operations of this database must be run into a P11/P15 with a maximum size greater than 1 TB.

**For example:** If your database size is 1.2TB, then you need to choose P11 or P15 because Maximum Storage choices for P11 and P15 is 4096.

[image]

You cannot downgrade is because Maximum storage choices for **P1-P6** is **500**, **750**, **1024**.

Comment: This does not answer the question, but affirms what the user already knew.  The question is, what method(s) can one use to downgrade a >1GB DB to <1GB DB if you are not using all the GB (meaning it could fit in a smaller server size).  From what I can tell, **all** operations tie it to the larger server size (restore, backup, etc).  A solution I was curious about was can you download the `.bacpac` file, restore to a local SQL instance and then export that information back out to a P1-P6 server instance?

Comment: @Tommy I was thinking about bacpac export-import but decided to ask community about other possible solutions before I proceed with this approach.